# Opencv character isolation

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4 in my Android application to do optical character recognition. I want to isolate each character before passing it on to the character recognition. I currently have 2 related problems:

1. I want to isolate individual characters, but for symbols like the colon (:), it will be considered as 2 symbols and be detected as a full stop.
2. If I apply vertical dilation to the image, symbols like the colon will be connected and opencv will combine them into 1 contour. The issue is that the lines of a receipt text is close to each other so this method will merge all the text together.

Can someone suggest a method where I will be connect symbols like : and = whilst segmenting individual characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Binary Connected Components and find the size of labels (i.e for symbols like : it contains only 1 or 2 number of labels and other symbols it will be more) this helps to isolate specific symbols.  Now can apply dilation alone for dots and erosion for brackets or vice versa.